# Need help with a solution for Linear Mapping

Tags: matrices

I'm looking at example questions for linear mapping, regarding matrices of linear mappings. I don't have much experience with them so I just want an explanation to a solution.

The question and solution (Used image to save time)
[image: question]

Could somebody explain the process of this question to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. You want to express the linear map $L$ on a basis $\beta$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you need to know how $L$ acts on this basis, for example if $\eta$ is the canonical basis:
$$
\eta= \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{array} \right)=e_1; \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{array} \right)=e_2; \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{array} \right)=e_3 \right\}
$$ 
Then, as in your solution you see that 
$$
Le_1=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
2 \\ 
1
\end{array} \right)=2e_1+2e_2+1e_1
$$
$$
Le_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{c}
-2 \\ 
1 \\ 
2
\end{array} \right)=-2e_1+1e_2+2e_1
$$
$$
Le_3=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
2 \\ 
1
\end{array} \right)=2e_1+2e_2+1e_1
$$
So
$$
[L]_{\eta}= (Le_1 \ Le_2 \ Le_3 ) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1
\end{array} \right)
$$ 
You have the expression of $L$ in the canonical basis, which of course coincide whit the original $L$. To work your example, is the same process but replacing $\eta$ by the basis $\beta$.